# React-native-firebase sound in silent mode

Tags: android, react-native

I implemented push notifications with React-native-firebase.
Push notifications come well and vibrations come well
Is it possible to force the sound to sound rather than vibrate in the silent mode??

Comment: Sorry i think it is not possible. You cannot change the settings on the users device. When the sound is turned off, it won't ring

Comment: I know some apps that can send notifications wiith sound even if device is in silent mode: Bsafe, Guarddian and some more safety apps

Comment: Any update? For forcing the push notification to sound even in silent mode?